# Show that the sequence defined by $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}(x_n^2+x_n+1), x_0=\sqrt 2$ diverge

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

I would like to show that the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}(x_n^2+x_n+1), x_0=\sqrt{2}$ is divergent. I would like to know if my proof is correct and to have a critical feedback.

First of all we can show by induction that the sequence is increasing.

Suppose that $x_{n+1}>x_n \ \forall n\ge0$. It is true for $n=0$, because $1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}>\sqrt{2}$. Now we want to show that is holds for $n+1$. So, we want to show that $x_{n+2}>x_{n+1}$. But,

$x_{n+2}>x_{n+1} \iff x_{n+1}^2+x_{n+1}>x_n^2+x_n \iff \underbrace{x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2}_{> 0}+\underbrace{x_{n+1}+x_n}_{>0}>0$

which is true because we supposed by induction that $x_{n+1}>x_n$. So, $(x_n)$ is an increasing sequence.

We know as well that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n+1}$, so we can resolve the following equation to find a limit $l$ of $(x_n)$ as it goes to infinity:

$3l=l^2+l+1 \Leftrightarrow l^2-2l+1=0 \Leftrightarrow (l-1)^2=0$, so the solution is $l=1$.

But, we have proved that $x_n$ is an increasing sequence and it is clearly bounded below by $\sqrt{2}$, so the solution $l=1$ doesn't hold. We conclude that $(x_n)$ diverge.

Comment: You implicitly proved the problem by absurdity. And your proof is correct.

Comment: It looks good. Perhaps to stress that we assume $\;\ell<\infty\;$ in order to be able to use arithmetic of limits at the end, and then to reach the contradiction so in fact it must be $\;\ell=\infty\;$ .

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers!

Comment: It is interesting that the recursion allows for increasing sequences which do not diverge. So all depends on the initial value. Take $0<x(0)<1$ and you find a an increasing sequence which converges to 1. This is in agreement with your proof, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is right, as others have mentioned in comments. Here is an alternative proof:
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}-x_{n} &= \dfrac13(x_n^2+x_n+1)-x_n\\
&=\dfrac13(x_n-1)^2
\end{align}
Note that, above shows in one go that the given sequence is non-decreasing and the limit, if exists, is $1$. So there is no convergence.